# Why does nginx adds a trailing slash to the original http request?

Tags: nginx

What makes nginx to add a trailing / to my requests? Currently this seems to break them.

```
location ^~ /custom/ {
    location  = /custom/.*\.css$ {
    alias /var/www/custom
    }

  alias /var/www/custom;
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
  uwsgi_modifier1 9;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
}
```

There are at least two problems with this config:

- if you request something like `/custom/xxx.css` the server will send the request to uwsgi
- the request send to uwsgi will be `/custom/xxx.css/` - and this additional slash will assure that event uwsgi would not return the file.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax you have used will force every request to go to uwsgi.

You should put

```
location  = /custom/.*\.css$
```

out of

```
location ^~ /custom/
```

Comment: What would be the syntax to use if I want **nested locations** and  match several file extensions, like `\.(css|png|jpg|gif)`.